# Calculate a VaR in R and add it to Data-Frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, finance

Good evening Community!

I am currently trying to calculate the **historic Value at Risk** in R. This requires a data frame of stock prices (`Daimler->DAI`) where there is a `date` column, a `price` and the `daily returns`. 
I found a package `PerformanceAnalytics` that allows me to calculate this value but it would only take all the values (`~3,600` observations) and return a single number. Instead, I want to have an added column that contains the specific calculated `VaR` for each date in time.

Since I am fairly new to `R`, I first had to figure out how self made functions can be made and came up with this:

```
require(dplyr)
# Read table from csv#
TableDAI <- read.csv2(xxx)
#Take columns from table to a dataframe#
DAI <- data.frame(Date=TableDAI$Date,  DAI.Close=TableDAI$Close)
### formulate an easy function for daily returns#
f.returns <- function(x, n=1){
  Returns <- x/lag(x,n)-1
  return(Returns)
}
## Open new column with returns##
DAI$DAI.Returns <- f.returns(DAI$DAI.Close)
```

So far so good.

Now if I want to do the next step it is necessary to calculate a `VaR` function which requires exactly `250` past observations of returns and then takes the `.05` quantile of these historic returns. Afterward, it would time this value by `sqrt(20)`.

My approach:

```
#Calculate the historic VaR for each row#
VaR.hist <- function(x, n=250, hd=20, q=0.05){
  quantil <- quantile(lag(x,n):x,q)
  VaR <- quantil*sqrt(hd)
  return(VaR)
}
```

Unfortunately, the result is just a column of `0`'s. Another issue that I see is that the first `250` can not be calculated since there are not enough observations.

I hope I brought the issue across and somebody can help.
Thanks!!

Comment: Hello! What do you mean? I thought my code is enough?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are defining VaR for this historical data. Do you just want the empirical 95th percentile? If so, assuming your vector is `x`

```
VaR_95 <- quantile(x, .95)
```

If on the other hand you want to say assume stationarity and gaussian "error" about the mean in order to estimate a simple standard deviation of the stock price from the historical prices and use that to calculate your VaR:

```
mu_hat <- mean(x)
sigma_hat <- var(x) %>% sqrt
VaR_95 <- qnorm(.95, mu_hat, sigma_hat)
```

I'm not sure if the part you're having trouble with is applying this function over the margin of a dataframe. If so...

```
my_func <- function(x, q) {
    mu_hat <- mean(x)
    sigma_hat <- var(x) %>% sqrt
    qnorm(q, mu_hat, sigma_hat) %>%
      return()
}

apply(df, 1, my_func, q = .95)
```

This can become a very complex topic, getting into regression and other modeling techniques because stock price is almost certainly not stationary, and your historical data probably does not capture the true potential for future variability. Hopefully though this answered your coding question.

Comment: ... seems like " enter" adds the comment.. I'm new to this lol.... Well the goal is to only measure the historic value at risk on a given day taking the empiric returns into account, just like you reckonned in your first point.The difficulty is for me to use only the last 250 observations in the input. I dont know how the correct syntax for this would be. Is the way I wrote my function actually how it is supposed to be written in R? Because your approach with an empty return() argument and the apply() function seems new to me. Thanks sir!!

Comment: Then is seems like you just need to first subset your data.frame - are the latest 250 observations in the rightmost 250 columns?
width <- dim(df)[2]; df[, (width-249):width]

FYI the return call is not empty, I piped (%>%) the result into the return

Comment: Hello! Thanks again for taking time. So I tried to adapt your advices to my code as follows: VaR.hist<- function(x, n=250, hd=20, q=0.05){
  width<-dim(x)[1]
  NA.x<-na.omit(x)
  quantil<-quantile(NA.x[(width-249):width],q)
  VaR<- quantil*sqrt(hd)%>%
  return()
} # Only thing is that my system tells me:       " Error in (width - 249):width : argument of length 0 "      Latest observation is added in a row, not column. I guess I'm far away from a usable solution also because the width is fix and I want it to change it relative to the row of the past observations.... Anyways, Thanks!